# Php Search - link to website from title

Tags: php, search

I have 2 fields in a mysql database called title and description.. The title is an article name and the description is a link to a website. I currently have the title coming up in the search results but when I click on the title I would like it to take me to the related description/website link using href.

I'm pretty sure I also need to add the description to this line of code:

```
$query=mysql_query("select * from posts where title LIKE '%{$key}%'");
```

How do I do that?

The site is http://vince.netau.net

```
<?php
    $key=$_GET['key'];
    $array = array();
    $con=mysql_connect","******_******","******");
    $db=mysql_select_db("a8814009_test",$con);
    $query=mysql_query("select * from posts where title LIKE '%{$key}%'");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
      $array[] = $row['title'];
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Comment: I hope those arent your real credentials. If so time to reset.

Comment: and that your not really using mysql_*

Comment: `* ` is all fields of a row.  It is accessible from the index. `$row['description']`, it would be better performance if you listed the columns. You should update your drive and use parameterized queries. This is open to SQL injections. You could build the link here, or you could have JS do it, depending on how you use that JSON.

Answer (score -1):

if i may get your question, you want user to be redirected to the saved in the column "description" ? the include this in you the HTML href in your while loop, `<a href='".$row['description']".">The link text here </a>`

Comment: Hi, I tried your line of code in the while loop but it didn't work for me.  Yes, I'm trying to get the description/website link to come up when I click the title in the search results.

Comment: So for example, in the mysql database I have an article called "Bitcoin is not Anonymous" in the title field and in the description field I have the link as http://www.fakelink.com. When "Bitcoin is not Anonymous" comes up in the search result, I want to be able to click it and have it take me to http://www.fakelink.com.   Thanks

Comment: Oh, you want to extract the link from the description, right?